# Cannot insert a null value but cannot insert a value since it is the primary key oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, insert, key

I can't insert a value into a primary key and I can't leave it blank. Why?
Here's the sql for creating the table in oracle

```
        CREATE TABLE users(
          id numeric(4),
          username varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
          password varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
        );
```

Here's also the sql for inserting the values in the table:

```
        insert into users (username, password) values ('jonaii', MD5('porter'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Primary keys have to have a value. That's a characteristic of primary keys.

In 12c Oracle finally added [auto-generation of synthetic keys](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHJHJC), but as you're still using an earlier version you'll need to use an explicit sequence:

```
create sequence user_id_seq;
```

There are options for configuring sequences: [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314).

Then

```
 insert into users (id, username, password) 
     values 
 (user_id_seq.nextval, 'jonaii', MD5('porter'));
```

Alternatively you could define a trigger on BEFORE INSERT to handle the sequence assignment.

---

> " However the MD5 doesn't work in oracle"

Hashing algorithms are implemented in two packages, [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS664), and the  older (deprecated) [DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_obtool.htm#ARPLS028).  You may need to get a DBA to grant execute on these packages.

Comment: Thank you very much! However the MD5 doesn't work in oracle. Could you help me with other terms with it?

Comment: @Jonaii, What do you mean "MD5 doesn't work"? What have you tried?